# Using the first isomorphism theorem to find group homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

During class we learned about the fiest isomorphism theorem, we were also told that it can be applied to find (the number of) group homomorphisms between two groups.

Now as an example I'm trying to find group homomorphisms between $A_n$ and $C*$

So I think that I have to find a smart finction $g$ which takes $A_n/Ker(f)$ to C*

However how do I go about it?

Comment: sorry, what is C*?

Comment: First isomorphism theorem is like induction, if have doubts about that certain function is the solution it's easy to check if the claim is true or not (just like in induction for sequences, if you know the formula it's "usually" easy to prove its correctness). So you need to come up with good target functions

Comment: @giantTortoise1729 C* is the multiplicative complex group

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$I assume $\C^{\star}$ is the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers.

Note that $\C^{\star}$ is an abelian group. So $A_{n}/\ker(f)$ must be abelian, For which values of $n$ is it the case that $A_{n}$ has proper normal subgroups with abelian quotient?

Comment: If $C*$ is abelian (which it obviously is) how does this imply that $A_n/ker(f)$ is abelian? I don't understand where you're going? @Andreas

Comment: Isn't this exercise about the first isomorphism theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is a normal subgroup, so homomorphisms are determined by normal subgroups. First assume $n\neq 3, 4$. In this case you may know $A_n$ is simple, so any map is either trivial or injective. Suppose you have an injective map. Then $A_n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$. You should check that isomorphism preserves commutativity. From here you can find a contradiction...

If $n=4$, $A_n$ has one non-trivial normal subgroup namely $V$, the Klein four group. By first isomorphism theorem you can show $A_4/V \simeq \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. So essentially you're determining maps from $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$. A hint for this: if $\varphi$ is your isomorphism, $g \in G$, then $\varphi(g^3) = \varphi(g)^3$.

For $n=3$, $A_n$ is abelian of order $3$, so the problem is similar to above.

Comment: $A_3$ is definitely  simple, but then also cyclic.

Comment: So I need to note that $A_n$ is simple except for $n=4$. Then I can note that  $A_4/V$ is isomorphic to $Z/3Z$ so I need to count the homomorphisms from $Z/3Z$ to $C*$, how do I do this?

Comment: the image of any $g \in G$ has order $3$ in $\mathbb{C}^*$. How many elements are there with this property.

Comment: Exacly one element? The trivial one, right? @gianttorttoise1729

Comment: Not quite. Recall the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: So I need to find all the roots of $x^3 - 1$?

Comment: Yes! and this shows where you can map each element.

Comment: Cool, and n=3? It $A_3$ has order 3 so can we use exacly the same mapping as for $A_4$?

Comment: Yes, the $A_3$ case is easier. Just to keep in mind for $n=4$ you're defining the map from $A_4 \to \mathbb{C}^*$ as you would a map from $A_3 \to \mathbb{C}^*$ but then quotienting by $V$.